# Was Michael Keaton's portrayal of Dogberry meant to be an homage to Monty Python?

Tags: monty-python, much-ado-about-nothing-1993

It seems pretty obvious and somewhat well accepted that Michael Keaton's portrayal of Dogberry in Kenneth Branagh's [Much Ado About Nothing (1993)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0107616/) was inspired by [Monty Python And The Holy Grail](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0071853/)

Has there ever been an official source verifying this fact?

Comment: Well, it starts with pretend horses…. all that's missing is the pair of coconuts

Comment: @Tetsujin I don't suppose they could find coconuts in Messina. The coconut's tropical.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**I don't believe there is an official source for any of this.**

The closest I can find is this [interview with Branagh](http://www.branaghcompendium.com/artic-kcs93.htm). Quoting from it:

> Certainly Branagh's most controversial bit of casting is having comic
>   actor Micheal Keaton portray Dogberry, the officious constable who is
>   just stupid and pompous enough to be dangerous. Employing a gravelly
>   "Ahoy, Matey! " pirate voice and pretending to ride an invisible
>   horse, Keaton's Dogberry seems guaranteed to blow the minds of
>   purists.
>
> "I've seen that part played so badly and so slowly on stage that it's
>   put the play on the floor," Branagh said. "***I wanted a brave, bold
>   performance that would provide a surreal quality.*** And the vividness
>   with which it's performed is exactly in the same spirit as the
>   performances of Will Kemp, one of Shakespeare's great clowns, who was
>   chucked out of the company for ad-libbing too much. I just know Kemp
>   would have given a very physical performance.
>
> "I figured Dogberry would be the hardest character to do for a modern
>   audience. He's one of those dangerous, thick people who believe they
>   are intelligent and responsible but are actually a few sandwiches
>   short of a picnic. ***For example, the whole idea of having him ride in
>   on an imaginary horse...We shot it several ways, including just having
>   him walk and run, but this way was bigger and bolder.***
>
> "The truth - and I'll probably be struck by lightning for saying so -
>   is that a lot of those Dogberry gags just aren't funny as written. The
>   fun is in the size of the man's ego and his assurances about his own
>   competence as a constable.
>
> "I believe the closest thing to genuine Shakespeare in this century
>   were the vaudevillians, who had to deal with rowdy audiences, a real
>   cross section of people. Michael gave us a very dangerous and slightly
>   bawdy performance, and I think it was absolutely right. "

So whether Branagh truly wanted this to be a tribute to Monty Python or not is unclear - instead, it seems he just wanted a completely surreal quality to the performance.

Python don't have exclusive rights on this *style* of surreal acting, so whilst  parts of Keaton's performance are certainly Python-esque, that's because Monty Python as a whole is simply surreal and bizarre - which is exactly what Branagh had asked Keaton to do.